# C# Application not running on windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7

I have made an application with C# which is targeted for .NET framework 4.5.2. I've made it with visual studio 2015.

I have tested it and it works fine on win 10/8.1/8. but on windows 7, it stops working right away, doesn't even show a form.

I have installed .NET framework 4.5.2, it didn't work. I've installed VCRedist 2017 both 64 and 32bit, still didn't work. I installed .NET framework 4.6.2, didn't work either.

I haven't used anything special in it except for ionic.ZIP.dll and Docotic.PDF.dll, both of which are not called at startup, so they are not the issue.

I also tested a very early version of my app which doesn't even have much in it, still a stopped working error right away.

So, is there anything I'm missing? Something I should install that I'm forgetting?

Note:
I have tested it on 2 different systems with windows 7, and both are for gamers, so they have most of the latest version of drivers and stuff installed. So I have no idea absence of what is causing this issue.

Any help will be appreciated.

Update:
I installed a windows 7 32bit on my PC on a virtual machine and all I installed was net framework 4.5.2 and the app worked.
so why is it not working on other windows 7s?

Another Note:
The other windows 7s I tested the app on were 64bit. but my windows 10 is 64bit and it works, also were the win 8 and 8.1 that I tested the app on. So I also doubt this be the issue, but I thought mentioning it might help.

Update2:
The app doesn't throw and exception, it gives a stopped working error with the event name being "CLR20r3".

Comment: What does the Event Log say?

Comment: Application in c# cannot crash imidietly (except application for UWP, but they should have popup message). Attach debugger at the begining of your application, or run it all in Visual Studio. This should give youy clear idea whats is going on with exception messages. Also if you have exception, that is showing up, edit your question or write it in comment.

Comment: Hi. please read the updates on the post.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue? I'm currently experiencing the same problem.

Comment: *sigh* I needed to install `Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015` which is already available on later versions of `Windows`.

Answer (score 0):

If an application stops working then it is a some kind of exception. In that case probably while loading the application. So there are 2 possibilities that I see:

1. Your application does something special in entry point (before creating main form) or in other thread that is created in entry point or in main form constructor.
2. You're missing some dlls.

What you should do:
Check the first point - if I'm right, debug the other thread. If that isn't the case then download DependencyWalker. This is an application that shows you all dlls that your application depends on. What's more, it shows you what dlls are missing in your system.

Just open your exe file in Dependency Walker and you'll see.

Comment: You may be missing dependencies such as `Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2013/2015` etc